# Aggregate roots in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, aggregateroot

I have registration form where user can input username and password and also create company at the same time(or chose one of existing companies). User have multiple companies and company have multiple users. How can I correctly choose User or Company to be my aggregate root(or both of them?).

I set Company as an aggregate root, it is ok in registration process I'm creating company and adding user to the company (company.addUsers(...)). But when I want to update user profile info(such as name, surname), I cannot do it in company aggregate root. I can create UserAggreageRoot and update user there but in this case it would affect to registration process(because in one transaction UserAggregate and CompanyAggregate would be updated, which is wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An aggregate can be viewed as an entity that covers a consistency boundary for a particular action.

If Company and User are in the same domain then you could use Company as an aggregate for creating users:

```
public class Company
{
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }

    public void AddUser(string forename, string surname)
    {
        User user = new User(forename, surname);
    }
}

public class User
{
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public User(string forename, string surname)
    {
        Forename = forename;
        Surname = surname;
    }
}
```

Your command handler can then create the company and call AddUser and then add the company to the unit of work via a repository.  You are only changing one aggregate (consistency boundary).  When the unit of work is committed your infrastructure will add the company and user within one transaction.

But then if you just want to change user's name (and there is no need for the Company to know about that) then you can retrieve a User an aggregate.

A domain class can be an aggregate in one context but not in another.

```
public class User
{
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public User(string forename, string surname)
    {
        Forename = forename;
        Surname = surname;
    }

    public void SetForename(string forename)
    {
        Forename = forename;
    }    
    public void SetSurname(string surname)
    {
        Surname = surname;
    }
}
```

The command handler will retrieve the User from the repository (and add the user to the unit of work) and make the changes to user before committing the unit of work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if I make User as an aggregate wouldn't it mean that now I have two aggregates?(Company and User), and this will mean that in registration process both User and Company aggregates are created, which is against the rule that only one aggregate should be created/updated in one transaction.

Comment: From the answer ... "A domain class can be an aggregate in one context but not in another."

Comment: How exactly can I solve my problem? You suggested that I make Company as an aggregate, and then User as another aggregate, but this will mean that in registration process I'm creating both User and Company aggregates.

Comment: No.  In the context of the registration process the Company is your aggregate, not the user.  In that use case, the user is just another entity that the Company Aggregate is managing.  In the change forename use case, the User will be the Aggregate.

Comment: So I need to keep duplicate User models? (one for each context)

Comment: Not necessarily.  The User model in my answer could be used as the aggregate when changing a name, or a child entity of the Company when registering in the first place.  I've just shown the 'first' iteration of a User model in the first code block, and then how that might be extended as a 'second' iteration in the second code block.

Comment: Ok. So you suggest that I need to have two bounded contexts and in first context set Company as aggregate and in second context set User as aggregate. And for registration use first context, for User update - second context?

Comment: No.  Where to draw the line between bounded contexts is a Strategic DDD decision.  I am working on the assumption that you've already decided that User registration and Company creation are in the same bounded context.  Which may well be fine.  My point is that you can use the SAME user class within that BC as an Aggregate Root for one use case but as a child entity of the Company Aggregate Root in another use case.

Comment: Neil W, I posted code, please take a look

Answer (score 0):

Neil W, if I understand correctly you suggest something like this

```
class User : Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public string Forename { get; protected set; }
    public string Surname { get; protected set; }

    //methods like Update(), ChangeStatus(), etc
}

class Company : Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public string Name { get; protected set; }
    public List<User> Users { get; protected set; }

    //...methods like AddUser(), ChangeName(), etc
}
```

But doesn't this mean that in registration process both User and Company AGGREGATES are created?

Comment: No.  Because in the registration use case the Company class is the aggregate (consistency boundary) and User class is just an Entity.  In the Change User Status use case you'll use User class as an Aggregate (consistency boundary).

Comment: Yes.  I do suggest something like the code you posted.

Comment: Isn't it against the rule that aggregates reference each other by identity instead of object reference?

Comment: Correct.  An AR should not reference another AR.  However, in the Registration Use Case ... the User is not an AR.  You do not retrieve the User from the Repository.  You do not add the user to the Repository.  You do not call any methods on the User directly. 
 Instead, you create a Company AR and let it manage the consistency boundary of adding a User entity to its collection.  When changing user status the consistency boundary of that use case can be managed by the User on its own, so in that use case the User becomes an AR.

Comment: I would encourage you to make all the discussions on the Neil's original answer. You can also use chat rooms to have detailed and elongated discussions.